# Linux use huge pages only

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, huge-pages

I have a x64 Linux system. The page size reported by `getconf` is 4 k:

```bsh
$ getconf PAGESIZE
4096
```

I want the kernel to use only large pages (2 M or 4 M) for all memory allocations. I've calculated that I have enough RAM to handle the memory
that will be wasted because of this.

How do I configure the Linux kernel so that it uses large pages for all allocations?

Answer (score 2):

It isn’t possible to configure the kernel to *only* use huge pages.