# Use only 2MB pages

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I would like to use a linux version in which only 2MB pages are used (i.e., no libhugetlbfs and transparent huge pages).
From other similar questions (e.g., [Linux use huge pages only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626899/linux-use-huge-pages-only)), I understood that it is not possible using the current kernel version.

I am really interested in doing this, and I will try to modify the kernel to do it.
Can you give me some advices in order to create a very minimal kernel version in which only 2MB page are used?

Comment: Maybe you would want to ask another question first: ***Why** is it currently not possible?* That would adjust your expectations, I think.

Comment: I work on the memory subsystem, and this isn't possible. I can't even imagine why someone would want to do this outside of hugepage merging considering the huge costs of wrong LRU decisions, cache pollution, and fragmentation.

Comment: @ChrisDown why it is not possible? Assuming that I do not want to worry about the problems you mentioned (e.g., I have enough memory to handle fragmentation). what are the current limitations that would not allow this solution?